# GWT, how to make the Loading Label properly?

Tags: gwt, loading, visible

I got a complicated loop which may take 1 or 2 sec to show the result, so I wanna put a indication to show the users to wait until the program finishes processing, so I make a Label("...loading...") & setVisible to false at the beginning of program & show visible to true before doing the loop then setVisible back to false after the loop finish.

```java
Label loadingLabel=new Label("...loading...");
public void onBind(){
    loadingLabel.setVisible(false);
}
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    loadingLabel.setVisible(true);
    // a lot of loop here
    loadingLabel.setVisible(false);
}
```

But after running, i didn't see the label visible. So what is the proper way to make Loading Lebel show properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check that you are adding the `Label` to the UI, maybe you didn't post that part of your code, but apparently it should be in `onBind`

Second, is `// a lot of loop here` synchronous or asynchronous?. If it is async, you have to hide your label at the end of your callback function.

Normally I prefer to use the `EventBus`, and when a large process starts (either it is a synchronous loop, or either a chain of asynchronous calls) y call `eventBus.fire(...)`, then when the last thing finishes, I call `eventBus.fire(...)` again.

```java
 Label loadingLabel = new Label("");
 RootPanel.get().add(loadingLabel);
 loadingLabel.setVisible(false)

 eventBus.addHandler(LoadingEvent.TYPE, new LoadingEvent.Handler() {
   public void onRequestEvent(LoadingEvent ev) {
     if (ev.getMessage() == null) {
        loadingLabel.setVisible(false);
     } else {
        loadingLabel.setText(ev.getMessage());
        loadingLabel.setVisible(true);
     }
   }
 });

 // show the label and display a customized message
 eventBus.fire(new LoadingEvent("message"))

 // a lot of loop here

 // hide the label 
 eventBus.fire(new LoadingEvent(null))
```

Of course you could have a more sophisticated  loading widget with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think you required something progress shows in looping. Javascript is having single thread only. so you can not do like this. you have to split execution of javascript using some mechanism. you can use [scheduler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html) for that.

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleIncremental(new RepeatingCommand() {
                @Override
                public boolean execute() {

if(somecodtion)
{
loadingLabel.setVisible(true);
return false;
}
else
{
 loadingLabel.setVisible(false);
return true;
}
}
```